# Scala - difference between for each loops

Tags: scala, loops, for-loop, foreach

Is there any difference between the two following statements. They achieve the same end, correct? Do they compile to the same Java code? Is there any performance difference between them or is it just a matter of preference/readability?

```
for (thing <- things) {
    doSome(thing)
}

things.foreach(
  thing =>
    doSome(thing)
)
```

Comment: Good question. I wonder if `for` is capable of applying any optimizations for specific (e.g. over arrays) types. Inspect the scala -print and, if that doesn't show any differences, the bytecode. (Try arrays and non-array types.)

Comment: Also, doesn't the 2nd form creates an additional anonymous type for the lambda with an *additional* call? Is this also case with the 1st form or can it elide another function/method call? It might be worthwhile to throw `things.foreach(doSome)` (or `doSome _` if it happens to be a method) into the mix for comparison ..

Comment: You know, you could just try both and diff the class files.

Comment: @user2246674 That wasn't aimed at you; it was aimed at OP, which should be clear since no @ tag.  And more users knowing how to do more things independently is more properly the point of SO than more questions on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`for` comprehensions are defined as simple syntactic translations. That's extremely important, because that allows *any* object to work with `for` comprehensions, it just has to implement the right methods.

IOW: the Scala Language Specification says that the first snippet gets translated into the second. So, if there were *any* difference whatsoever between the two snippets, that would be a violation of the spec and thus a very serious compiler bug.

Some people have asked for, and even implemented, special treatment of certain objects (e.g. `Range`s), but those patches were always rejected with the argument that special treatment for special types would only benefit those special types, whereas making Scala faster *in general* will benefit everybody.

Note that with Macros, it's probably possible to detect, say, iteration over a `Range` purely as a simple C style `for` loop and transform that into a `while` loop or a direct tailrecursive inner function, without having to change the spec or add special casing to the compiler.

Comment: Hey Jorg, thanks! It really helps to understand **why** the two compile to the same Java code. I definitely learned something here. [More reading for anyone interested](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111).

Answer (score 15):

They are identical.  Given

```
class Foreach {
  val things = List(1,2,3)
  def doSome(i: Int) { println(i) }
  def one { for (thing <- things) { doSome(thing) } }
  def two { things.foreach{ thing => doSome(thing) } }
}
```

the bytecode is

```
public void one();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokevirtual   #40; //Method things:()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
   4:   new #42; //class Foreach$$anonfun$one$1
   7:   dup
   8:   aload_0
   9:   invokespecial   #46; //Method Foreach$$anonfun$one$1."<init>":(LForeach;)V
   12:  invokevirtual   #52; //Method scala/collection/immutable/List.foreach:(Lscala/Function1;)V
   15:  return

public void two();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokevirtual   #40; //Method things:()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
   4:   new #55; //class Foreach$$anonfun$two$1
   7:   dup
   8:   aload_0
   9:   invokespecial   #56; //Method Foreach$$anonfun$two$1."<init>":(LForeach;)V
   12:  invokevirtual   #52; //Method scala/collection/immutable/List.foreach:(Lscala/Function1;)V
   15:  return
```

Comment: Thanks Rex, thats great! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Per [scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html):

> As always, for-expressions can be used as an alternate syntax for expressions involving foreach, map, withFilter, and flatMap, so yet another way to print all elements returned by an iterator would be:
>
> for (elem <- it) println(elem)

"Alternate syntax" would mean identical.

Comment: @user2246674 if you find details with a devil in them, submit a bug report to the team responsible for scala's documentation, because the language is clear.

Comment: a more up to date version of the linked doc can be found on the new [docs.scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org) website: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html

Comment: I would be shocked if you compiled the classes with the same everything (var names) and the classes would be equal. I bet there will be a difference.

Comment: @AdamGent then do so and post as a separate answer.  Would also recommend submitting a bug report to scala team.

Answer (score -1):

Basically

a `for` loop is a construct that says

> perform this operation n. times

a `foreach` loop is a construct that says

> perform this operation against each value/object

Comment: Not so. Read the other answers to get a better understanding of why `for` isn't really a loop (it's a "`for` comprehension") and it can also be used "against each value/object".